# Зависает Unity при инстанциации MonoBehaviour скриптов в Start

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Пытаюсь создать c `Instantiate` массив объектов из selector. Но код создаёт огромное число объектов (видно слева пару объектов как Cube(Clone), затем идут пару как Cube (Clone)(Clone) и т.д) и через секунду юнити (2018.4) намертво виснет.

Что не так с кодом?

```
public class Bgr : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numSelectors = 2;
    public GameObject[] selectorArr;
    public GameObject selector; //selected in the editor

    void Start()
    {
        selectorArr = new GameObject[numSelectors];
        for (int i = 0; i < numSelectors; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(selector, new Vector3((float)i, 1, 7), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            go.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
            selectorArr[i] = go;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, а если инстанциировать префаб игрового объекта - то все нормально работает. Но если объект есть в игровой сцене, то все летит к чертям. Вообще, как я по-своему понял похоже на то, что метод проверяет наличие игрового объекта и делает из него массив, а потом в массив переписываются его копии и так далее массив растет. Вроде как выходит,  что метод Start() вызывается несколько раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в `Start` вызывается `Instantiate`, который создаёт копию `selector`. Как я понимаю, на этом `selector` висит скрипт `Bgr`.

В итоге, после создания нового объекта на сцене на нём будет также висеть скрипт `Bgr`, у которого вызовется `Start`, у которого вызывается `Instantiate` и так до бесконечности создаются копии, пока Юнити не умрёт.